# How do I need organize Java classes in order to save data to Firebase that has uid as parent of its children

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to organize data in Firebase like this, also I want that task_id_1 is type UID. How do I need to organize Java classes in order to do that?

```json
{
  "users": {
    "uid_1": {
      "tasks": {
        "task_id_1": {
          "name": "Ime prvog taska",
          "date": "2023-05-15"
        },
        "task_id_2": {
          "name": "Ime drugog taska",
          "date": "2023-05-16"
        }
      }
    },
    "uid_2": {
      "tasks": {
        "task_id_3": {
          "name": "Ime trećeg taska",
          "date": "2023-05-17"
        },
        "task_id_4": {
          "name": "Ime cetvrtog taska",
          "date": "2023-05-18"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can add tasks like this:

```java
public class User {
    private String uid;
    private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

But in that way I will get members of array list instead of uid as a parent for Task class.

Comment: To understand better, you need a class with fields that can be mapped in the above database schmea?